# What exactly does numpy.exp() do?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, exp

I'm very confused as to what np.exp() actually does. In the documentation it says that it: "Calculates the exponential of all elements in the input array." I'm confused as to what exactly this means. Could someone give me more information to what it actually does?

Comment: Well, have you tried it?  `print np.arange(10), np.exp(np.arange(10))` (for python2).

Answer (score 147):

The exponential function is `e^x` where `e` is a mathematical constant called Euler's number, approximately `2.718281`. This value has a close mathematical relationship with `pi` and the slope of the curve `e^x` is equal to its value at every point. `np.exp()` calculates `e^x` for each value of `x` in your input array.

Answer (score 66):

It calculates *e<sup>x</sup>* for each *x* in your list where *e* is Euler's number (approximately 2.718). In other words, `np.exp(range(5))` is similar to `[math.e**x for x in range(5)]`.

Comment: For beginner: `math.e` is the Euler's number. Try `import math; print(math.e) # 2.718281828459045`. And `**` is Python code for power.

Answer (score 38):

exp(x) = e^x where e=  2.718281(approx)

In Python we can use the `exp` function from `numpy` ([docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.exp.html)):

```
import numpy as np

ar=np.array([1,2,3])
ar=np.exp(ar)
print ar
```

outputs:

```
[ 2.71828183  7.3890561  20.08553692]
```

Comment: Your code gives me following error:
ufunc 'exp' output (typecode 'd') could not be coerced to provided output parameter (typecode 'l') according to the casting rule ''same_kind'"

Comment: If you change the [1,2,3] to [1.,2.,3.], the error should disappear. I think it happens because of a conversion of the numpy values to object type. So you put them as float, and it works :) or maybe it happens only in Python 2x, I tested in python 3.6 and it worked.

Comment: `assert np.exp(np.log(2.5)) == 2.5`